# Magento2 how to use setCustomAttribute properly

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

I'trying to set custom attribute to quote item by method `setCustomAttribute` from `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item`. Below is my code

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_item_set_product">
        <observer name="product_point_quote" instance="Vendor\Producer\Model\Observer\Sales\Quote\Item\SetCustomAttribute"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**SetCustomAttribute.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Producer\Model\Observer\Sales\Quote\Item;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class SetCustomAttribute implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $quoteItem->setCustomAttribute('producer', $product->getProducer());
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Below is code of `setCustomAttribute` from `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item`

```
public function setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $attributeValue)
{
    $customAttributesCodes = $this->getCustomAttributesCodes();
    /* If key corresponds to custom attribute code, populate custom attributes */
    if (in_array($attributeCode, $customAttributesCodes)) {
        $attribute = $this->customAttributeFactory->create();
        $attribute->setAttributeCode($attributeCode)
            ->setValue($attributeValue);
        $this->_data[self::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES][$attributeCode] = $attribute;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

It doesn't work because the method `getCustomAttributesCodes()` returns an empty array. The question is how to use method `setCustomAttribute()` in the proper way? How to populate array with custom attributes codes from `getCustomAttributesCodes()`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what version you are using, but looking at the current version of Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item there is no function setCustomAttribute. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item.php

I've done this in the past by adding an additional column to the quote item table for my custom data.

First add the column to you the quote item table and and any additional tables you'll want the field mapped to upon conversion. The example below assigns data to the quote item and transfers it to the sales order item upon conversion.

**Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
  public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
    $setup->startSetup();

    $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
      $setup->getTable('sales_order_item'),
      'producer',
      [
        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'comment' => 'Producer'
      ]
    );

    $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
      $setup->getTable('quote_item'),
      'producer',
      [
        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'comment' => 'Producer'
      ]
    );

    $setup->endSetup();
  }
}
```

**SetCustomAttribute.php** needs a minor modification to set the producer property

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Producer\Model\Observer\Sales\Quote\Item;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class SetCustomAttribute implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $quoteItem->setProducer($product->getProducer());
    }
}
```

There is a bug, https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5823, that prevents custom fields from mapping properly on quote conversion. When this is resolved you can use **fieldset.xml** for moving the field data upon conversion like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="quote_convert_item">
            <field name="producer">
                <aspect name="to_order_item" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

To workaround the bug I used a plugin.
**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
    <plugin name="vendor_producer_quote_to_order_item" type="Vendor\Producer\Plugin\Quote\QuoteToOrderItem"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin/Quote/QuoteToOrderItem.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Producer\Plugin\Quote;

class QuoteToOrderItem
{
  public function aroundConvert(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
    $proceed,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item,
    $additional = []
  ) {
    $orderItem = $proceed($item, $additional);
    $orderItem->setProducer($item->getProducer());

    return $orderItem;
  }
}
```